# FillNaN with multiple conditions and using n-1 and n+2 values with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I have the following data frame:

```
d = {'T': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'Val1': [10, np.NaN, 14, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 20, np.NaN, np.NaN, 30]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

T   Val1
1   10.0
2   NaN
3   14.0
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   20.0
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  30.0
```

I want to fill the NaN with different values depending on certain conditions:

1. If the value `V` is NaN and if `V+1` and `V-1` are not NaN then `V=np.mean([V+1, V-1])`
2. If the values `V` and `V+1` are NaN and if `V-1` and `V+2` are not NaN then I want to fill them following this formula: `V=np.cbrt([(V-1)*(V-1)*(V+2)])` AND `V+1=np.cbrt([(V-1)*(V+2)*(V+2)])`
3. Other NaN should be removed

So the wanted datatable should look like:

```
T   Val1
1   10.0
2   12.0
3   14.0
7   20.0
8   22.89
9   26.20
10  30.0
```

I was able to do the `V=np.mean([V+1, V-1])` by the following command:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df.ffill(), df.bfill()]).groupby(level=0).mean()

T   Val1
1   10.0
2   12.0
3   14.0
4   17.0
5   17.0
6   17.0
7   20.0
8   25.0
9   25.0
10  30.0
```

But I don't know how to incorporate the different conditions.
I tried using `np.select()` but I can't find a way to recover following and previous value and add them to the conditions.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
def condition_2(a, b): #a = V-1, b = V+2
    return np.cbrt((a) * (a) * (b))

def condition_3(a,b): # a = V-2, b=V+1
    return np.cbrt((a) * (b) * (b))


d = {'T': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'Val1': [10, np.NaN, 14, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 20, np.NaN, np.NaN, 30]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
cond_1 = df['Val1'].isnull() & df['Val1'].shift(1).notna() & df['Val1'].shift(-1).notna()
cond_2 = df['Val1'].isnull() & df['Val1'].shift(1).notna() & df['Val1'].shift(-1).isnull() & df['Val1'].shift(-2).notna()
cond_3 = df['Val1'].isnull() & df['Val1'].shift(-1).notna() & df['Val1'].shift(1).isnull() & df['Val1'].shift(2).notna()

df['Val1'] = np.where(cond_1, (df['Val1'].shift(1) + df['Val1'].shift(-1))/2, df['Val1'])
df['Val1'] = np.where(cond_2, condition_2(df['Val1'].shift(1), df['Val1'].shift(-2)), df['Val1'])
df['Val1'] = np.where(cond_3, condition_3(df['Val1'].shift(2), df['Val1'].shift(-1)), df['Val1'])

df.dropna(subset=['Val1'], inplace=True)
```

`OUTPUT`

```
    T       Val1
0   1  10.000000
1   2  12.000000
2   3  14.000000
6   7  20.000000
7   8  22.894285
8   9  26.207414
9  10  30.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution using `np.split` and a custom function. Basically split on non-NaN values and iterate over each split to evaluate whether to drop NaN or change NaN:

```
def nan2notna(arr1, arr2):
    mask = pd.isna(arr1)
    if len(arr1[mask]) > 2:
        return arr1[~mask] 
    else:
        if len(arr1[mask]) == 2:
            arr1[mask] = [np.cbrt([(arr1.iloc[0])*(arr1.iloc[0])*(arr2.iloc[0])]), np.cbrt([(arr1.iloc[0])*(arr2.iloc[0])*(arr2.iloc[0])])]
        elif len(arr1[mask]) == 1:
            arr1[mask] = np.mean([arr1.iloc[0], arr2.iloc[0]])
        else:
            pass
        return arr1

splits = np.split(df['Val1'], np.where(pd.notna(df['Val1']))[0])[1:]
out = (df.merge(pd.concat([nan2notna(arr1, arr2) for (arr1, arr2) in zip(splits, splits[1:]+[None])]).to_frame(), 
               left_index=True, right_index=True)
       .drop(columns='Val1_x')
       .rename(columns={'Val1_y':'Val1'})
       .round(2))
```

Output:

```
    T   Val1
0   1  10.00
1   2  12.00
2   3  14.00
6   7  20.00
7   8  22.89
8   9  26.21
9  10  30.00
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine and such a nice way to solve that. However, my dataframe have about 2M rows and this method is around 10 times slower than the other answer from @Muhammad Hassan. 
Thank you tho' learned a lot thanks to you !